# Pass Environment Variables to Angular Container Docker : Post Build

Tags: angular, docker

Recently i started working on Dockerizing my Angular App.
After adding all the necessary files ( Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, entrypoint.sh) i managed to build my image successfully.

Then i had the need of passing environment variables to the app , in order to pass the back end api url which i did'nt want to add it neither to the code itself or the Dockerfile.

After some search i followed this article

https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/using-os-environment-variables-in-angular-with-docker/

So to summarize

- i installed @angular-builders/custom-webpack
- i changed the angular.json file to now use the new builder instead of the default
- i created a custom-webpack.config.js file which was added in the configuation

  ```
  const webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
   plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      $ENV: {
        ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENVIRONMENT),
        SomeAPIKey: JSON.stringify(process.env.SomeAPIKey),
        SomeOtherAPIKey: JSON.stringify(process.env.SomeOtherAPIKey)
      }
     })
    ]
   };
  ```
- I created and exported an interface which would have the variables declarations i want to import

  ```
    import { Env } from 'src/typing';

    declare var $ENV: Env;
    export const environment = {
     production: true,
     environment: $ENV.ENVIRONMENT,
     ApiUrl:$ENV.API_URL
  };
  ```
- Then the last step is to add the environment variables in the Dockerfile something like

  ```
    FROM node:10.15.0 as builder

    # SET ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
    ENV ENVIRONMENT="development"
    ENV API_URL="xxx"

    RUN ng build --prod
  ```

Everything worked great even if i saw that if the

```
ENV API_URL=x
```

command was after the

```
RUN ng build --prod
```

Then this value was not picked up.

So my problem is how should i add this environent variable outside of the Dockerfile which shouldnt have these kind of details and also overcome the problem with the order of the ENV command ?

For example can these variables be passed at runtime.
Asp.net core images for example can receive environment variables at 
docker run..

I tried and saw that these env variables are not received from the angular app if they are passed post build.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: what you did in the last, did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If `API_URL` not used in `RUN ng build --prod` or other steps of `docker build`, then you no need to specify it in `Dockerfile`, just pass it to container when run, as next:

```
docker run --env API_URL="xxx" --env VAR2=value2 ubuntu
```

You can refers to [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file), then you no need to care the `ENV` order in `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Unfortunately as i mentioned in the post , when adding the environment variables in docker -run then the values are not picked up.

Comment: Er, `docker run --env API_URL="xxx" ubuntu env`, this will show that all env in the container, `API_URL` as environment variable definitely in container. You just have an nodejs application in running time to get the environment variable `API_URL`, or I misunderstand your points?